# Derivative of $t\sin(\pi t)$

Tags: calculus

Please can someone give the derivation steps for why the derivative of $t\sin(\pi  t)$ at zero is zero?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think the derivative is zero? The derivative has zeros, but it doesn't vanish identically. Do you want to locate the zeros of the derivative?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $f(t)=t\sin(\pi t)$ is $f'(t)=\sin(\pi t)+\pi t\cos(\pi t)$ *when taken with respect to $t$.*

When taken with respect to another variable, then the derivative *is* $0$, since the function is treated as a constant.

Alternatively, you can evaluate the derivative at certain values of $t$ and the result of those values is zero. For example, when $t=0$, $f'(t)=0$.

Comment: All I am asking for is the simple steps of how the derivative of the equation is equal to zero. When I apply the rules of derivatives, I get something else than zero. I learning calculus for the first time, and your answer adds to my confusion. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, I get the same derivative, but Mathematica gives me an answer of zero. I still don't see it?

Comment: The derivative of the equation is not zero when the derivative is taken with respect to $t$. Perhaps you are entering something incorrectly into mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(t) =\pi t\cos(\pi t)+\sin(\pi t)$$

$$f'(0)=\pi(0)*\cos(\pi*0)+\sin(\pi*0)$$

$$f'(0)=0+\sin(0)$$

$$f'(0)=0+0$$

$$f'(0)=0$$

Basically the left part of the derivative simplifies to $0$ because we're multiplying it by $0$. The right part of the derivative is $0$ because sine of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and its the same derivation I have, but for other values other than zero, the derivative is not zero. So, why evaluate it for only zero?

Comment: I only evaluated it for $0$ because that's what your question asked me to do.

Would you like me to do something else with it?

Comment: Point made, but I was just unclear why Mathematica gave me a result of zero when I expected equation of the derivative. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm sorry to say I don't know why Mathematica is doing that.